# How to measure the time elapsed since the last message received from a datagram socket in Poco C++?

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

My code monitors a datagram socket (implemented in the Poco framework), and I'd like to get notified if there were no messages received after a certain time. I have an infinite loop to monitor the socket, but the loop stops at `receiveFrom()` function, if no messages were received.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//Poco includes
#include "Poco/Net/DatagramSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/SocketAddress.h"

int port = 5000;

Poco::Net::SocketAddress sa(Poco::Net::IPAddress(), port);
Poco::Net::DatagramSocket dgs(sa, true);
char buffer[1024];

for (;;)
    {
        int n = dgs.receiveFrom(buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1, sender);
        buffer[n] = '\0';
        std::string line = buffer;

        //Do something with the message

    };
```

Comment: i didnt find corresponding overload of `receiveFrom` but there is one for `receiveBytes` that takes a timeout

Comment: You set the timeout on the Poco socket object. You do not need to include a timeout in the `receiveFrom(..)` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set a timeout on your Poco socket.

```
Poco::Timespan wait_time( 10000 ); // microseconds

// from header file  Poco/Net/Socket.h
sa.getReceiveTimeout( wait_time )
```

Then check the number of bytes returned by `receiveFrom(..)` is > 0 or check for a timeout exception. Use this opportunity to do your other work.

Comment: Thank you @JimmyNJ for the reply! After tinkering with ```setReceiveTimeout(..)``` it turned out that the socket waits for the given ```wait_time``` after which it throws an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up @Foktris 95. I'll change the answer.